Reduce regular polygon size and correct braces
I am using this code to generate a tikz picture:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Define colors
        \definecolor{technical}{RGB}{199,233,192}
        \definecolor{nontechnical}{RGB}{255,193,127}
        \definecolor{total}{RGB}{117,187,253}

        % Draw the main box
        \draw[thick, fill=white] (-3,10) rectangle (12,2);
        
        % Technical losses
        \node[draw, circle, fill=technical, minimum size=2cm] (technical) at (0,7.5) {\textbf{Perdas Técnicas}};
        
        % Non-technical losses
        \node[draw, rectangle, fill=nontechnical, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm] (nontechnical) at (5,7.5) {\textbf{Perdas Não Técnicas}};
        
        % Total losses
        \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, fill=total, minimum size=2cm, text width=2.5cm, align=center] (total) at (10,7.5) {\textbf{Perdas Totais}};

        
        % Plus sign
        \node at (2.25,7.5) {\LARGE +};
        
        % Equals sign
        \node at (7.75,7.5) {\LARGE =};
        
        % Technical losses details

        \draw[thick] (-1.5, 6) -- (-1.5,4.5) node[anchor=north] {};
        \draw[thick, ->] (-1.5,4.5) -- (-1,4.5);
        
        \node at (-0.8, 4.5) {\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\{};
    
        \node[align=left] at (0.9,4.5) {
            \textbf{Perdas no Cobre} \\
            \textbf{Perdas no Núcleo}
        };
        
        % Non-technical losses details

        \draw[thick] (3,6) -- (3,4.5) node[anchor=north] {};
        \draw[thick, ->] (3,4.5) -- (3.5,4.5);

        \node at (3.7, 4.5) {\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont\{};
        
        \node[align=left] at (5.4,4.5) {
            \textbf{Fraude} \\
            \textit{Bypass} \\
            \textbf{Suborno} \\
            \textbf{Não Pagamento}
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

This is the result:

I have tried reducing the minimum size value in the regular polygon node, but it does not change anything. Why? How can I reduce it's size to be similar to the circle and square?
And regarding the braces, the first one (related to the circle) is fine), but the second is small and should brace all 4 rows. The thing is, if I increase it's size, it does not yield a "nice" result... any ideas how to correct that?

minimum size=2cm but the text exceeds 2cm.

@pascal974 you are right, reducing both to minimum size and text width to 1cm solved that part.

Fine. // I suggest you post an answer with this solution.

for the brace, I pos ta possibility with the calligraphylibrary

ADDENDUM
I added some options to frame the entire drawing or part of it relatively, first there is the one that uses the drawing space through the backgrounds library, which will frame everything you draw, then through the calc library that will draw a rectangle from one point to another, only these points are relative to certain nodes. and finally using the fit library that encloses the nodes in a node according to the node names fit=(node_name_1)(node_name_2)...(node_name_etc)
ADD-RESULT:

ADD-MWE:
\documentclass[border=3.14pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,backgrounds,fit}
%Global custom color names
\definecolor{Tech}{RGB}{199,233,192}
\definecolor{NonTech}{RGB}{255,193,127}
\definecolor{total}{RGB}{117,187,253}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        Shape/.style={
            draw,
            fill=#1,
            minimum width=2cm,
            minimum height=2cm,
            align=center,
            font=\bf\small
        },
        Subtext/.style={
            font=\bf\tiny,
            align=left,
            inner sep=1pt
        },
        Brace/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                brace,
                amplitude=3pt,
                raise=0pt
            }
        },
        background rectangle/.style={%By background library
            rectangle,
            rounded corners,
            shade,
            right color=Tech,
            left color=total,
            draw=black!40!black!60,
            dashed
        },show background rectangle% To show the rackground.
        ]
        \node[Shape=Tech,circle](PT){Perdas\\Técnicas};
        \node[right=0.5em of PT,scale=1.5](PLUS) {+};
        \node[Shape=NonTech,rectangle,fill=NonTech,right=0.5em of PLUS] (NT){Perdas Não \\ Técnicas};
        \node[right=0.75em of NT,scale=1.5](EQUALS) {=};
        \node[Shape=total,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,below right=-1.25em and 1em of EQUALS,inner sep=-2pt](TOT){Perdas \\ Totais};
        \node[below right=2em and -3.5em of PT, Subtext](PT-sub){Perdas no Cobre\\ Perdas no Núcleo};
        \node[below right=1em and -5em of NT, Subtext](NT-sub){Fraude\\Bypass\\Suborno\\Não Pagamento};
        \node[below right=1em and -4em of TOT, Subtext](TOT-sub){Item1\\Item2\\Item3\\Item4\\Item5\\Item6\\Item7};
        \draw[->](PT) -- (PT.180 |- PT.-90) |- ($(PT-sub.180)+(-0.7em,0)$);
        \draw[->](NT.south west)-- +(-135:0.5em) |- ($(NT-sub.180)+(-0.7em,0)$);
        \draw[->](NT.south west)-- +(-135:0.5em) |- ($(NT-sub.180)+(-0.7em,0)$);
        \draw[->](TOT.210)-- +(-135:0.5em) |- ($(TOT-sub.180)+(-0.7em,0)$);
        \draw[Brace](PT-sub.south west)--(PT-sub.north west);
        \draw[Brace](NT-sub.south west)--(NT-sub.north west);
        \draw[Brace](TOT-sub.south west)--(TOT-sub.north west);
        \node[below =1em  of TOT-sub, Subtext](note) {the background is the \\ canvas of the drawing\\ and is adjusted to the content};
        %Using Calc lib prety manual
        \draw[red]($(PT.180 |- PT.90)+(-2pt,2pt)$) rectangle ($(TOT.-30 |- TOT-sub.-90)+(2pt,-2pt)$);
        %Using fit lybrary
        \node[fit=(PT)(TOT-sub)(TOT.-30),draw,blue,dotted,thick](){};
        \node[fit=(NT)(NT-sub),draw,green!50!black,dotted,thick,inner sep=10pt](){};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

In the case of nodes you must use the line break to prevent the size from expanding, you can also control the internal separation via inner sep, remember that the definitions indicate the minimum size, which is exceeded by the content size like this You must be careful about the size of the content, then the text in the nodes is not defined within them but through the font node property, so you can modify the font size and type without having to do it for each line and The spaces between lines will be respected, the rest is that since you use a lot of text to describe where you are going, the positioning library will help you avoid the use of absolute coordinates indicating at what distance you place one node from another, in some cases I use negative values for intersection distances. And the best method for brackets is through decorations, so if the list is large the bracket grows proportionately.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[border=3.14pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
%Global custom color names
\definecolor{Tech}{RGB}{199,233,192}
\definecolor{NonTech}{RGB}{255,193,127}
\definecolor{total}{RGB}{117,187,253}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            Shape/.style={
                draw,
                fill=#1,
                minimum width=2cm,
                minimum height=2cm,
                align=center,
                font=\bf\small
            },
            Subtext/.style={
                font=\bf\tiny,
                align=left,
                inner sep=1pt
            },
            Brace/.style={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    brace,
                    amplitude=3pt,
                    raise=0pt
                }
            },
        ]
    \node[Shape=Tech,circle](PT){Perdas\\Técnicas};
    \node[right=0.5em of PT,scale=1.5](PLUS) {+};
    \node[Shape=NonTech,rectangle,fill=NonTech,right=0.5em of PLUS] (NT){Perdas Não \\ Técnicas};
    \node[right=0.75em of NT,scale=1.5](EQUALS) {=};
    \node[Shape=total,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,below right=-1.25em and 1em of EQUALS,inner sep=-2pt](TOT){Perdas \\ Totais};
    \node[below right=2em and -3.5em of PT, Subtext](PT-sub){Perdas no Cobre\\ Perdas no Núcleo};
    \node[below right=1em and -5em of NT, Subtext](NT-sub){Fraude\\Bypass\\Suborno\\Não Pagamento};
    \node[below right=1em and -4em of TOT, Subtext](TOT-sub){Item1\\Item2\\Item3\\Item4\\Item5\\Item6\\Item7};
    \draw[->](PT) -- (PT.180 |- PT.-90) |- ($(PT-sub.180)+(-0.7em,0)$);
    \draw[->](NT.south west)-- +(-135:0.5em) |- ($(NT-sub.180)+(-0.7em,0)$);
    \draw[->](NT.south west)-- +(-135:0.5em) |- ($(NT-sub.180)+(-0.7em,0)$);
    \draw[->](TOT.210)-- +(-135:0.5em) |- ($(TOT-sub.180)+(-0.7em,0)$);
    \draw[Brace](PT-sub.south west)--(PT-sub.north west);
    \draw[Brace](NT-sub.south west)--(NT-sub.north west);
    \draw[Brace](TOT-sub.south west)--(TOT-sub.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


We are missing here the main box \draw[thick, fill=white] (-3,10) rectangle (12,2); where all the shapes must be inside. How can you draw it without absolute coordinates?

@Murilo , I added something about it...

For the brace, we can use the calligraphy library.
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
    decorations.pathreplacing,%
    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
    BC/.style = {decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, 
                    amplitude=5pt,
                    raise=2pt,
                    aspect=#1},
        very thick,
        pen colour={black}},
    }
    
\node[align=left](T)
{
    \textbf{Fraude} \\
    \textit{Bypass} \\
    \textbf{Suborno} \\
    \textbf{Não Pagamento}%
};
\draw[BC=0.5]   
(T.south west) --  (T.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


